# generate links with a greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script in Greasemonkey that will generate link's in  a frame, but with my limited Javascript knowledge I don't really know how to do this.

Example of subject:

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" cols="*,280" rows="*">
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,200">
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="75,*">
<frame scrolling="NO" name="bannerFrame" src="banner.php">
<frame scrolling="auto" name="mainFrame" src="main.php">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<body class="framemainbg" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<table class="areadescription" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<br>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="personlistcaption">Text:</p>
<p class="listusersrow">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<td valign="top">
<b>Text </b>
Text -
<a href="fight.php?action=attacknpcmenu&checkid=1347789191&act_npc_id=764">Attack</a>
-
<a class="fastattack" onclick="this.href += '&yscroll=' + window.pageYOffset;" href="fight.php?action=attacknpc&checkid=8409099&act_npc_id=764">Quickattack</a>
<br>
Text
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<form name="formular">
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,0">
</frameset>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,360">
</frameset>
<noframes><body> Text </body></noframes>
</html>
```

Example of desired Output :

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" cols="*,280" rows="*">
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,200">
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="75,*">
<frame scrolling="NO" name="bannerFrame" src="banner.php">
<frame scrolling="auto" name="mainFrame" src="main.php">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<body class="framemainbg" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<table class="areadescription" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<br>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="personlistcaption">Text:</p>
<p class="listusersrow">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<td valign="top">
<b>Text </b>
Text -
<a href="fight.php?action=attacknpcmenu&checkid=1347789191&act_npc_id=764">Attack</a>
-
<a class="fastattack" onclick="this.href += '&yscroll=' + window.pageYOffset;" href="fight.php?action=attacknpc&checkid=8409099act_npc_id=764">Quickattack</a>
-
<a href="fight.php?action=slapnpc&amp;checkid=8409099&amp;act_npc_id=764&amp;mark=0">Hit</a>
-
<a href="fight.php?action=chasenpc&amp;checkid=8409099&amp;act_npc_id=764&amp;">Chase</a>
<br>
Text
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<form name="formular">
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,0">
</frameset>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" cols="*" rows="*,360">
</frameset>
<noframes><body> Text </body></noframes>
</html>
```

This Links should be generated:

```
-
<a href="fight.php?action=slapnpc&amp;checkid=8409099&amp;act_npc_id=764&amp;mark=0">Hit</a>
-
<a href="fight.php?action=chasenpc&amp;checkid=8409099&amp;act_npc_id=764&amp;">Chase</a>
```

The 'checkid=...' and the 'npc_id=...' must be the same value as in this link:

```
<a class="fastattack" onclick="this.href += '&yscroll=' + window.pageYOffset;" href="fight.php?action=attacknpc&checkid=8409099act_npc_id=764">Quickattack</a>
```

Comment: Somehow this question got on the "newest" section....werid

Comment: @David Likely because it was just migrated from webapps so it is new to the SO feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this is really just basic [HTML DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM), there's nothing [GreaseMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)-specific here.

First, I'm going to assume that the link you want to copy the URL parameters from is the only one with `class="fastattack"`, since [that makes finding it easy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName):

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName( 'fastattack' )[0];
if ( link ) {
    // we found the link, do stuff with it...
```

Next, we need to [generate the first new link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.createElement):

```
    var newlink = document.createElement( 'a' );
```

...make it [point to the URL we want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement):

```
    newlink.href = link.href.replace( 'action=attacknpc', 'action=slapnpc' );
```

...and give it [the link text we want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent):

```
    newlink.textContent = 'Hit';
```

Next, we [insert the new link into the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) just after the original link, like this:

```
    var nextNode = link.nextSibling;
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( newlink, nextNode );
```

Oops, we forgot to insert [the delimiter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.createTextNode) first!  No worries, we can still do that:

```
    var delim = document.createTextNode( ' - ' );
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( delim, newlink );
```

Now we can just do the same for the other link:

```
    var newlink2 = document.createElement( 'a' );
    newlink2.href = link.href.replace( 'action=attacknpc', 'action=chasenpc' );
    newlink2.textContent = 'Chase';
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( delim.cloneNode( true ), nextNode );
    link.parentNode.insertBefore( newlink2, nextNode );
```

This time, I remembered to insert the delimiter first.  I used the same `delim` node as above, but I [made a copy of it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) because I wanted to insert *another* identical delimiter, not move the original delimiter to a new position in the DOM.

Finally, we need to close the `if` block, and that's it:

```
}
```

(Disclaimer: I have not actually tested the code above.  I *think* it should work, but there might be bugs or typos that I've missed.)

**Edit:** Changed the code to insert the new links just after the original, rather than at the end of the parent paragraph.

**Addendum:**
If you have multiple links with `class="fastattack"` in the document, and wish to apply the code above to each of them, you can do that by replacing the first two lines above with a loop over all the links, instead of just the first one:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName( 'fastattack' );
for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    var link = links[i];
    // now do stuff with link just like above
```

Comment: But now I have this formation: 
Text
Text
Text Text Attack - Quickattack
Text    Hit - Chase


Text Text Attack - Quickattack
Text    Hit - Chase
but I need this formation:
Text
Text Text Attack - Quickattack - Hit - Chase
Text
Is this possible?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean; I hadn't noticed that there was more text after the links.  It should be fixed now, I think.

Comment: If there are more than just one   <p class"listusersroe">...</p>  so there are two different checkid= & npc_id= what must I change that there are the right links are generated?

Comment: You can use a `for` loop over the results of `getElementsByClassName()`; see edit to answer above.

Comment: There is only one little problem: If I click on the generated links I must reload the page to generate the other links again. Is there a way to auto-refesh (onchange?) the site if i cklick on the generated links?

Comment: That's weird... I think it must have something to do with the fact that the site is using frames, but I have no experience with that myself. (It's been a while since I last even _saw_ a site using frames, much less tried to script them with GreaseMonkey.) Could you perhaps give a link to the site for testing?

Comment: Wait, obvious question: do the `@include` lines for your script actually match `fight.php`?  Remember that GreaseMonkey scripts are run separately [for each frame in a frameset](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Prevent_Execution_in_Frames) (as long as the `@include` lines match).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you very much.